# Red-and-White Megaphone App coming up unsolicited

Tags: malware, samsung-galaxy-s-9

For about a month, an unknown app has been occasionally coming up on my cell phone's screen, interrupting whatever I'm doing, displaying a black screen and that rolling circle in the middle that means I should wait.

It lasts a couple seconds or more, then leaves without a trace, returning focus to whatever I was doing before.

When it lasts a little longer, I'm able to press that lower-left button that "zooms out" to all open apps, each with its logo on the top. I'm then able to close it, or take a screenshot.

The logo of our mystery app is a red-and-white megaphone, which I do not recognize. See attached screenshot.

[image: Zoomed-out screenshot of red-and-white megaphone app]

That logo does not appear in the list of all installed apps.

The timing seems to be random.

**What is this app, what is it doing, and how do I get rid of it?**

The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S9+

I'm running Android version 9

The phone has served me flawlessly for over a year before getting this issue.

I do have many apps installed, some of which are ad-supported games. They all either came preinstalled, or came from the Google App Store.

Comment: Do you happen to be near your PC when this happens, because troubleshooting requires it? Setup [tag:adb] in your PC, and whenever this issue occurs again, run these three commands:`adb shell dumpsys window windows > windows.txt`, `adb shell dumpsys activity activities > activities.txt`, `adb shell dumpsys activity recents > recents.txt`. Upload these three files somewhere on pastebin or add their content into your question.